# next-line-add-newlines breaks history browsing by cursor arrow keys

Tags: key-bindings, navigation

I've always hated "end of buffer" errors, so my `.emacs` contains

```
(setq next-line-add-newlines t)
```

Recently, I've noticed that when browsing a history by cursor arrows (up/down for previous/next), e.g. when opening a file, the down arrow adds a line instead of showing the previous element in the history. <kbd>M-p</kbd> and <kbd>M-n</kbd> work correctly.

I there a way how to fix the behaivour in the way it was in older Emacs versions, i.e. <kbd>↓</kbd> adds new lines in a normal buffer, but browses the history in the mini-buffer?

Comment: `M-x report-emacs-bug`, would be my suggestion.

Comment: @Drew: That's what I did. https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=29529

Comment: Great. Thx......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported the issue as a bug, suggesting the following patch:

```
diff -u <(zcat /usr/local/share/emacs/25.3/lisp/simple.el.gz) ~/simple.el
--- /dev/fd/63  2017-12-01 23:45:06.338468797 +0100
+++ /home/choroba/simple.el     2017-12-01 23:45:04.166450109 +0100
@@ -2038,6 +2038,7 @@
   (interactive "^p")
   (or arg (setq arg 1))
   (let* ((old-point (point))
+         (next-line-add-newlines nil)
         ;; Remember the original goal column of possibly multi-line input
         ;; excluding the length of the prompt on the first line.
         (prompt-end (minibuffer-prompt-end))
```

The patch has been accepted.